# Cisco ASA Site-To-Site VPN change peer IP

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-asa, site-to-site-vpn

We use Cisco ASA 5510 and I have to change peer IP address on the current  Site-To-Site VPN.

Every time when I have similar issue I deleted current vpn and then create new one from scratch.After Googling I found some solutions to change only peer IP  but they  not working for me.

This is [link](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/68883-change-the-peer-ip-address-site-to-site-asa-vpn-connection-via-gui) to the last post when I lost couple of hours without result.

**My question is:** Can I change only peer IP address when I need or I have to make new vpn from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change the peer IP address without create new Site-To-Site VPN
In general you have to change two parameters.

- peer IP address
- tunnel group name

According your link they changed only first setting. 
If you check your log file you have to find wrong tunnel group name or something like that.

Anyway this is very good Step by Step guide for your case - [Cisco ASA – Changing VPN IP Addresses](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000391). It works.

Comment: You are completely right. It works.:)) Thanks for your time.